# How to create two label inside an <input> element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two label elements. I want the first one to be shown all the time but the second one needs to be hidden on focus.

How I can get this result with jQuery?

```
<dd>
    <label for="checkcode" class="check_label">=</label>
    <label for="checkcode" class="checkcode_label">enter code</label>
    <img src="/captcha" id="captcha" />
    <input id="checkcode" type="text" name="checkcode" value="" />
</dd>
```

I need to use the two defined "label" to get the needed result. Is not possible to set "value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This label is not necessary use the input and CSS for styling. If your target browser is modern capable use placeholder attribute, and css :focus to change style on input:

1. When input is not focused

   .checkcodeClass {
     border : 0;
   }
2. When focused

   .checkcodeClass:focus {
     border : 1px solid black;
   }

For browsers that not support placeholder:

1. Use jquery to put placeholder https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder

For browsers that not support CSS :focus:

1. Use jquery 'on' with blur and focus to alternate class.

Comment: I will give them a try and check if Modernizr (is already loaded) take care about placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkcode").focus(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "enter code" ){
        $(this).val("");
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "" ){
        $(this).val("enter code");
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/mY9Nn/1/).

We're emptying the `value` attribute of the input when it gains focus and setting it back to "enter code." It's a bit more complex than that because we are checking to see if the value is currently "enter code" when it gains focus (in which case it empties it, otherwise it does not, which keeps user entries in there if it gains focus again). When it loses focus, we are checking to see if it is empty, in which case we change it to "enter code" (this keeps user entries in when it loses focus).

Comment: Thanks, I forget to explain better, I must place both label elements inside the input field, wihtout to use value to set. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Nenad: Why would you? Also, why can't you use value?

Comment: It's a multilanguage site where I can not put static text inside JS files.

Answer (score 0):

Use [focusin()](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) function.

```
$('label.second').focusin(function(){
    $(this).addClass('notShown');
})
```